# How to check for resource file existence at run-time [grails]?

Tags: spring, grails, gsp

I need to test whether a resource file (an image, for instance) exists and if not, I will display another image.
My GSP view code looks like:

```
<% if (resExists(dir: "images", file:"img.jpg")) {%>
  <img src="${g.resource(dir:'images',file: 'img.jpg')}">
<% else { %>
  <img src="${g.resource(dir:'images',file: 'noimg.jpg')}">
<%}%>
```

How can I test for a file existence in Grails? What is the code of the method `boolean resExists()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer:

```
def resExists(resPath)  {
    def resFile = grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource(resPath)
    resFile?.exists()
}
```

or

```
def resExists(resPath)  {
    def resFile = request.servletContext.getResource(resPath)
    resPath
}
```

And you call it with `resExists('images/img.jpg')`

Comment: Good job.  You might try to make that into a custom tag for your application.  See http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.2%20GSP%20Tags

Answer (score 2):

I've done the following in GSP:

```
<g:set var="flag" value="${new File(grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath("images/sgs-geosol/sign/${sec.username()}.gif")).exists()}"></g:set>

<g:if test="${flag}">

</g:if>
```

The code below returns the real path of the Grails app:

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath("")
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not work for me when used from within a plugin, packaged as a production war. I now use the following:

```
GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator groovyPageLocator

def resExists(resPath) {
    def resource = groovyPageLocator.findTemplateByPath(resPath)
    resource
}
```

Comment: How did you inject this. It always returns null for finding resources