# Want to load custom per page resources dynamically if exists

Tags: grails

I have requirement of loading custom styles sheet and js files into gsp page dynmically if they exists..As they are dynamic, it cannot be part of any modules of Resources.groovy.

We search if the resource files exists like below and if so loaded it.
js/views/$controller/${action}-custom.js"

Which is the best way to load or implement this requirement.

Comment: This question is too general. Load from where? Load into? There are missing details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about dynamic loading of js files in your GSP view, you could check if the file exist, before loading it. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17086071/1385627).

Comment: I agree, but I would use the `GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator` answer, not the accepted one - that way your code will be future proof.